# Az Function EventGrid trigger from Blob Storage upload slow to start

Tags: azure-functions, azure-blob-storage, azure-eventgrid, azure-blob-trigger

I have implemented a system where FrontEnd upload a photo into a blob container, then Blob fire an event on EventGrid on "*BlobCreated*" that trigger an Az Function which generate a thumbnail and save it into a MongoDb instance.
I follow the rules Microsoft suggest to avoid cold start, using an Elastic Premium Plan and configure one minimum Instance to be always warm.
[image]

[image]

I do not have lots of events per seconds, to be honest I could have 30 minutes without any events and then some minutes where users pushes images on blob.
I noticed from the Application Insight logs that if too much time passes between one upload event and another, function need some seconds (3 - 4 seconds) before first log (I have a log at just the begin of my function).
[image]

If I upload three photos consecutively, time between upload and function start is some milliseconds.
[image]

Function is initialized as following:
**ThumbnailGenerator.cs**

```
namespace ThumbnailGeneratorV2;

public class ThumbnailGenerator
{
    private readonly IReceiptDbService _dbManager;
    private readonly IMimeInspector _mimeInspector;
    private readonly int _thumbnailDimension;

    public ThumbnailGenerator(
        IReceiptDbService dbManager,
        IMimeInspector mimeInspector)
    {
        _dbManager = dbManager;
        _mimeInspector = mimeInspector;
        int.TryParse(Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("ThumbnailDimension"), out _thumbnailDimension);
    }

    [FunctionName("ThumbnailGenerator")]
    public async Task Run(
        [EventGridTrigger] EventGridEvent eventGridEvent,
        [Blob("{data.url}", FileAccess.Read, Connection = "AzureWebJobsStorage")]
        Stream myBlob,
        ILogger log)
    {
        log.LogInformation("Function Start");
        ...
    }
```

**Startup.cs**

```
[assembly: FunctionsStartup(typeof(ThumbnailGeneratorV2.Startup))]
namespace ThumbnailGeneratorV2;

class Startup : FunctionsStartup
{
    public override void Configure(IFunctionsHostBuilder builder)
    {
        builder.Services.AddSingleton<IMimeInspector, MimeInspector>();
        builder.Services.AddSingleton<IReceiptDbService, ReceiptDbService>();
        builder.Services.AddSingleton<IDbRepository, DbRepository>();
    }
}
```

P.S. the Az Function is outbounded with a VNET cause database is in a private network.

Someone has some suggestions how to keep the function really alive?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

> The function is taking much time to start when there is a long gap between events.

This is due to the **function app is unloaded from memory** after a period of inactivity to save resources. When a new event comes then the function app needs to be loaded back into memory.

- To make the function app alive always, you need to use [Azure Functions Premium plan](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-premium-plan?tabs=portal).

And also, you need to configure the function app to use a minimum number of instances to ensure that there is always at least one instance running.

[image]

**Another approach**

Use `Azure Event Grid's retry policy` to resend events that were not processed due to cold start.

[image]

- Use Azure Application Insights to monitor function app's performance and identifying issues.

[image]

[image]

- Using Azure Container Instances to run function app in a containerized environment.

For more information refer to [Function Diagnostics](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-diagnostics) and [Function App settings.](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-how-to-use-azure-function-app-settings?tabs=portal#always-on)

Comment: My Function has already a Premium Plan and has 1 always running instance. Please look the screens in the post. Moreover the event is not lost (even if I have configured a retry policy), function take only some seconds to wake up.

Comment: Since you are experiencing a delay of a few seconds when the function is not used for a while, it is possible that the function is being unloaded from memory due to inactivity. When a function is unloaded from memory, it must be reloaded the next time it is called, which can cause a delay.

Comment: And to prevent the function from being unloaded due to inactivity, you can try using the Always On feature in Azure App Service. This feature ensures that your function is always running, even when there are no requests being processed.

And Set the Always On option to On. This should help keep your function warm and ready to handle requests, even when there is no activity for a long period of time.